# Spread key with two variables

Tags: r, tidyverse

I need to spreap a dataframe with two variables but I cant do that with tidyr package.
In my example, I want to add the month variable to the key, something like `key = c("level", "month")`

Here what I did :

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

name <- sample(letters[1:5], 10, replace = T)
level <- sample(1:3, 10, replace = T)
month <- sample(1:12, 10, replace = T)

df <- data.frame(name, level, month)

df  %>% 
  group_by(name, month, level) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  spread(., level, n, sep = "_")
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please show what the expected output should look like?

Comment: Check @akrun output, something similar to it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be `pivot_wider` (it seems the 'n' would be `spread` based on the combination of 'month', 'level') from the dev version of `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # 0.8.3.9000
df %>% 
  group_by(name, month, level) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c('month', 'level'), values_from = 'n')
# A tibble: 5 x 11
#  name  `5_3` `3_3` `4_1` `12_2` `1_1` `9_3` `10_1` `10_3` `7_1` `11_1`
#  <fct> <int> <int> <int>  <int> <int> <int>  <int>  <int> <int>  <int>
#1 a         1    NA    NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA     NA
#2 b        NA     1     1      1    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA     NA
#3 c        NA    NA    NA     NA     1     1      1      1    NA     NA
#4 d        NA    NA    NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     1     NA
#5 e        NA    NA    NA     NA    NA    NA     NA     NA    NA      1
```

---

If we want to use `spread`, then `unite` to a single column and use `spread`.  It should also work in the latest `CRAN` version of `tidyr` (`0.8.3`)

```
df %>% 
  group_by(name, month, level) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  unite(monthlevel, month, level) %>%
  spread(monthlevel, n)
```

---

Or using `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df)[, .N, .(name, month, level)], name ~ month + level, value.var = 'N')
```

Comment: Thanks exactly the output expected, but my R doesnt find pivot_wider function (I updated tidyr package to 0.8.3 version)

Comment: @DimitriPetrenko. I ussed thee dev version of `tidyr` `0.8.3.9000`. You can insstall it from the `github`

Comment: Thanks I will check it

Comment: @DimitriPetrenko.  You can also `unite` (updated the answer) and then `spread`

Comment: Thank you very much exactly what I needed, interesting all this possibilities